# How to include currently open java projects in a eclipse-plugin's classpath?

Tags: classpath, testng, eclipse-plugin

For a custom **eclipse plugin**, how to include projects currently in eclipse package explorer to its **classpath**.

This custom eclipse plugin is trying to execute **TestNG**, but projects open in eclipse are not visible to testNG. I am hoping that including projects in eclipse plugin's current classpath will resolve this issue.

Basically its related to, changing runtime classPath of an Eclipse plugin programmatically.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but will help you out in your thinking of what you need to code.

Create a poup menu contribution to projects that have a plugin nature with a label somthing like "Add Java Projects To Class Path".

In your action or command handler this is the code I am thinking that needs to be in place:

- Get a reference to your selected plugin project.
- Create a list that will contain a list of all open java projects in the workspace.
- Make sure you add `org.eclipse.core.resources` to you bundle dependencies.
- Get the list of Projects in the workspace by calling

  ```
  ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
  ```
- For each project call `if(project.getNature("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")` does not return null.
- Add the project to your list of open java projects. Also make sure you are not adding the plugin project you have selected as it also has a java nature. If you want to only add java projects but not plugin projects you will need to do an additional check if it has a plugin nature and if so exclude it.

Now the fun part. Get a reference to your plugin project which you should have if you are implementing a command handler or `IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate` interface.

Because a plugin project also has a java nature you can do this once you have a reference to your plugin IProject

```
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(mySelectedProject);
IClasspathEntry[] entries = javaProject.getRawClasspath();


List<IClassPathEntry> newEntries - new ArrayList<IClassPathEntry>(); 
// for each IProject in your active java project list. 
foreach(IProject project: activeProjects)  { 
    IJavaProject currentProject = JavaCore(project); 

    IPath srcPath= currentProject.getPath().append("target/generated-sources");
    IClasspathEntry srcEntry= JavaCore.newSourceEntry(srcPath, null);
    newEntries.add(srcEntry);   
}

// after processing each open java project we found and adding a new IClassPathEntry we now set the 
// updated class path entries on the selected plugin/java project. 

newEntries.add(entries); 
IClassPathEntry[] newEntryArray = newEntries.toArray(new IClassPathEntry[newEntries.size()]);

javaProject.setRawClassPath(newEntries, null)
```

Now the part I don't fully know: saving your changes to disk, take a look at this post: 
[Saving modified AST in a new file with eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878710/saving-modified-ast-in-a-new-file-with-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for your time Duncan.
But I am trying to figure out a way to include those IClassPathEntries to that of my plugins classpath in runtime. Say my plugin is installed in your eclipse, then it should be able to include existing java projects in your eclipse in its own classpath.