# How to add enum constant field to IType

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, eclipse-jdt

What should be the `value` value to add a new enum constant to the type `type`?

```
public void addEnumConstant(IType type, String value){
    if(type.isEnum()){
        type.createField(value, null, false, null);
    }
}
```

Edit:
I guess I was too brief, so I add more information about my problem

I am using the JavaModel framework and want to add an enum constant to IType object. I want to avoid explicit use of AST.

It is easy to add a new method to a type, by following code:

```
IType type = [...];
type.createMethod("public void method(){}", null, false, null);
```

Also I can add a variable field:

```
type.createField("public int var", null, false, null);
```

but I have no idea how to add an enum constant.

Comment: What's IType ? is it enum?

Comment: I guess you are using the Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree code to try and add a new field to a type. You are getting down votes because you have not made this clear enough and people don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType

Answer (score 0):

`IType` offers a method to create a type with the given contents. This may be used for Enum as well.

```
createType(String value, IJavaElement sibling, boolean force, IProgressMonitor monitor)
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you have access to the compliation unit, then you can create an EnumConstantDeclaration AST node in your IType.

```
ICompilationUnit iCUnit = type.getCompilationUnit()

// convert iCUnit to CompilationUnit

EnumConstantDeclaration constant = compilationUnit.getAST().newEnumConstantDeclaration();
constant.setName(parse.getAST().newSimpleName("constant name"));
```

Code for converting ICompilationUnit to CompilationUnit :

```
//Get the compilation unit for traversing AST
final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
parser.setSource(javaElement.getCompilationUnit());
parser.setResolveBindings(true);

final CompilationUnit compilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

Comment: I want to add a constant to existing enum declaration, so I cannot use createType of IPackageFragment, but rather createField from IType

Comment: After your update: This is what I will eventually have to do, if there is no other way. The point is that it is not that simple as in your snippet. First I need to convert ICompilationUnit to CompilationUnit and then apply the changes using TextEdits. I did it in about 20 lines of code, so the alternative of using createField() in one line was really tempting, especially that I do not use AST explicitly anywhere else in my code.

Comment: Agree that the `createField()` is a much elegant option and uses JDT alone. But not sure of any another alternative.

Comment: I was just traversing an Enum and can find that the `IType.getFields()` gives the Enum constant list, which may infer that the Enum constant is also a IField. Have you tried creating the constant with the `createField()` method?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer does not describe how the AST can be converted back into Java source code. This seems to be possible (https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html), but looks quite complicated.

Comment: @FelixM Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878710/saving-modified-ast-in-a-new-file-with-eclipse-plugin/12879941#12879941